Get the transaction from SolanaPay post request, send transaction failed in phantom
I want to use the SolanaPay in my dapp, the client (dapp) can get the transaction by the post request which is implement in my server. The transaction is about sol transfer. It is successful when sign and send transaction by browser extension. When i test send the transaction by mobile (ios Phantom), i scan the QR code and there is the transaction detail that shows i transfer 0.01 SOL. I click the confirm button and there is no response, and there is no the transaction when i check the signature on solscan. Thanks for reply.


There was a bug with Solana Pay transactions in Phantom and the fix will ship in the next release: v24.23.0
